# how to use function correctly in java

Tags: java, class, oop, object, methods

Given an array arr[] of N positive integers, where elements are consecutive (sorted). Also, there is a single element which is repeating X (any variable) number of times. Now, the task is to find the element which is repeated and number of times it is repeated.
here is my code:-

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class GFG
 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
     {
         Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
         int t,n,i,left,rightleftid,rightid;
         t=sc.nextInt();
         while(t!=0){
             n=sc.nextInt();
             int arr[]=new int [n];
             for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                 arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
             }
             left=0;right=n-1;
             mid=(left+right)/2;
             leftid=funcleft(arr[],n,left,right);
             rightid=funcright(arr[],n,left,right);
             System.out.println(arr[leftid]+" "+(rightid-leftid+1));
             t--;
         }
     }
     static int funcleft(int arr[],int n,int left,int right){
         mid=(left+right)/2;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid+1]&&arr[mid]!=arr[mid-1])
         return mid;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid-1])
         return funcleft(arr[],n,left,mid-1);
         if(arr[mid]-arr[0]<mid)
         return funcleft(arr[],n,left,mid-1);
         else
         return funcleft(arr[],n,mid+1,right);
     }
     static int funcright(int arr[],int n,int left,int right){
         mid=(left+right)/2;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid-1]&&arr[mid]!=arr[mid+1])
         return mid;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid+1])
         return funcright(arr[],n,mid+1,right);
         if(arr[mid]-arr[0]<mid)
         return funcleft(arr[],n,left,mid-1);
         else
         return funcleft(arr[],n,mid+1,right);
     }
}
```

the compiler is showing some errors

> [errors:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8XFC.png)

plzz elaplain me what i m doing wrong i m a beginner in java

Comment: `leftid=funcleft(arr[],n,left,right);` Remove the `[]`. You are using a variable there, not creating a new array.

Comment: i got it thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all.....the thing which i dont know was - during a function call if i want to pass an array(arr[]) as argument then i just need to pass its name(arr) as argument not the square brackets([]) along with it. Here is my new optimized error free code which has been submitted successfully.

````
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class GFG
 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
     {
         Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
         int t,n,i,left,right,leftid,rightid;
         t=sc.nextInt();
         while(t!=0){
             n=sc.nextInt();
             int arr[]=new int [n];
             for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                 arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
             }
             left=0;right=n-1;
             leftid=funcleft(arr,n,left,right);
             rightid=funcright(arr,n,left,right);
             System.out.println(arr[leftid]+" "+(rightid-leftid+1));
             t--;
         }
     }
     static int funcleft(int arr[],int n,int left,int right){
         int mid=(left+right)/2;
         if(mid==0)
         return mid;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid+1]&&arr[mid]!=arr[mid-1])
         return mid;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid-1])
         return funcleft(arr,n,left,mid-1);
         if(arr[mid]-arr[0]<mid)
         return funcleft(arr,n,left,mid-1);
         else
         return funcleft(arr,n,mid+1,right);
     }
     static int funcright(int arr[],int n,int left,int right){
         int mid=(left+right)/2;
         if(mid==n-1)
         return mid;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid-1]&&arr[mid]!=arr[mid+1])
         return mid;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid+1])
         return funcright(arr,n,mid+1,right);
         if(arr[mid]-arr[0]<mid)
         return funcright(arr,n,left,mid-1);
         else
         return funcright(arr,n,mid+1,right);
     }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should just call

```
funcleft(arr,n,left,mid-1);
```

without the brackets for your error.

But the code that you wrote does not solve the problem you are describing. You say "given" the array but are creating t number of arrays with length n, and filling up the elements of the array yourself which may or may not be sorted depending on your input.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to compile the code, there are a few problems:

- scope of the variables
- code line is java should end with  ';'
- also you do not need embeded class

As an example you can take this version of your code which passes compilation:

```
 package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;


class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t, n, i, left, right, leftid, rightid, mid;
        //int t,n,i,left,right,left,id,rightid;
        t = sc.nextInt();
        while (t != 0) {
            n = sc.nextInt();
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            left = 0;
            right = n - 1;
            mid = (left + right) / 2;
            leftid = funcleft(arr, n, left, right);
            rightid = funcright(arr, n, left, right);
            System.out.println(arr[leftid] + " " + (rightid - leftid + 1));
            t--;
        }
    }

    static int funcleft(int[] arr, int n, int left, int right) {
        // mid = (left + right) / 2;
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == arr[mid + 1] && arr[mid] != arr[mid - 1])
            return mid;
        if (arr[mid] == arr[mid - 1])
            return funcleft(arr, n, left, mid - 1);
        if (arr[mid] - arr[0] < mid)
            return funcleft(arr, n, left, mid - 1);
        else
            return funcleft(arr, n, mid + 1, right);
    }

    static int funcright(int[] arr, int n, int left, int right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == arr[mid - 1] && arr[mid] != arr[mid + 1])
            return mid;
        if (arr[mid] == arr[mid + 1])
            return funcright(arr,n, mid + 1, right);
        if (arr[mid] - arr[0] < mid)
            return funcleft(arr,n, left, mid - 1);
         else
        return funcleft(arr,n, mid + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Secondly, you might want to think about the algorithm itself, as a simple solution you can use Map e.g. TreeMap to iterate through the elements and bump the counter for every member.

Comment: yes but i have just started learning ds n i dont know how to use mapping....btw thanks for  the reply:)

Answer (score 0):

Those specific compile Errors are due to the way, how arrays are defined and accessed in Java:

While defining the varible `arr` which should point to your stored array use the brackets after the type, not after the name, because the it's a varible of the type array of intergers, therefore the declaration should be

```
int[] arr=new int [n];
```

Then when using the whole array as such, and not a specific element, use only the name of the variable which is just `arr` so when accessing `funcleft` or `funcright` it should be

```
funcleft(arr,n,left,right);
```

or the same for `funcright`.

After fixing those errors, you'll run in further compile errors which are not yet given by the compiler as he doesn't come that far. A working example of your code could look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class GFG
 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
     {
         Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
         int t,n,i,left,right,rightleftid,rightid,leftid,mid;
         t=sc.nextInt();
         while(t!=0){
             n=sc.nextInt();
             int[] arr=new int [n];
             for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                 arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
             }
             left=0;
             right=n-1;
             mid=(left+right)/2;
             leftid=funcleft(arr,n,left,right);  
             rightid=funcright(arr,n,left,right);
             System.out.println(arr[leftid]+" "+(rightid-leftid+1));
             t--;
         }
     }
     static int funcleft(int arr[],int n,int left,int right){
         int mid=(left+right)/2;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid+1]&&arr[mid]!=arr[mid-1])
         return mid;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid-1])
         return funcleft(arr,n,left,mid-1);
         if(arr[mid]-arr[0]<mid)
         return funcleft(arr,n,left,mid-1);
         else
         return funcleft(arr,n,mid+1,right);
     }
     static int funcright(int arr[],int n,int left,int right){
         int mid=(left+right)/2;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid-1]&&arr[mid]!=arr[mid+1])
         return mid;
         if(arr[mid]==arr[mid+1])
         return funcright(arr,n,mid+1,right);
         if(arr[mid]-arr[0]<mid)
         return funcleft(arr,n,left,mid-1);
         else
         return funcleft(arr,n,mid+1,right);
     }
}
```

Though that won't exactly solve your given task as @Gokberk Gul pointed out